# Chrome detects current Desktop and Mobile Website Opens

Tags: google-chrome, blogger

I have a website that is using two different views, namely desktop and mobile. Generally for blogs hosted on Blogger will display a mobile version of your blog when combined `?m=1` at the end of the blog url.

My website is quite risky if the user turns using chrome or another browser to the desktop but with an additional open my web `?m=1`

**Now I ask.**

Is it possible to prohibit the user opens the mobile version of my blog when he used the computer / PC / Laptop?

Please explain, thank you

Answer (score 1):

We can detect the UserAgent of the browser and if it isn't mobile, then we can replace the query parameter `m=1` with `m=0` (which redirects to the desktop version)

Adding the following code to the `<head>` tag of the template should work (The UserAgent condition courtesy of [What is the best way to detect a mobile device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3514784/what-is-the-best-way-to-detect-a-mobile-device-in-jquery/3540295#3540295) ) -

```
<script>
if(!/Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent) && location.search.match("m=1") != null) 
{
location.search = location.search.replace('m=1','m=0')
}
</script>
```

**Note:** Make sure that you are using the Custom Mobile template to make this work (In Blogger dashboard > Template tab > Gear Icon > Check *Yes. Show mobile template on mobile devices.* > Select **Custom** in *Choose mobile template* dropdown )

Comment: Thanks, I will try first android device